# Rails Controller Naming Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this is something I've been trying to wrap my head around, but it doesn't really make too much sense as the internet has varying levels of explanation regarding this:

**Why is @question lowercase, and why does it have an @ sign?**

**In that same line, why is it "Question" (uppercase, no @ sign?)**

Is there some sort of detailed explanation here? I generally understand that @variables mean that it's an instance variable and is available in the view. But this other capitalization business is not making sense. But why are there @instance variables in the controller?

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  @question.save 
  redirect_to @question
end

def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

# private makes all the methods private, so they aren't accessible in the view..
private
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

Comment: `Question` is the name of the class and `@question` is a reference to an instance of the class. For the sake of clarity it could have been `@fish`. `@` is prepended to the name to define the scope of the variable; you want to instantiate the variable in the controller and still be able to use it in the view. Without the `@` the variable would have been local to the controller and the view could not have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `@` declare a variable at the moment of its initialization as an instance variable, that's to say a variable that will be available from the controller to the view, so, if you say for instance in your controller:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

Then you can use it in your view, the same way, with `@`:

```
<%= @question %>
```

What's at the right side of the variable name, the value, is what says, from the model `Question`, use the `find` method, to "find" the question with `id` equal to the the `params[:id]` you've sent.

It's the way you access the model by using `ActiveRecord`, your models will be always in its singular form and capitalized.

If you define as example an instance variable typing your model "downcased", you'll see that Rails takes it as an instance variable, and won't be able to find it anywhere.

The reason of why there are instance variables in the controller because it's the way you can make your variables be available in your views, other way you won't have access to them.

Comment: Okay I understand that it's being initialized as an instance variable, and will be available in the view. But, what about on the same line, question comes as "Question" without an @ sign -- What's going on there?

Comment: `Question` is the classname of the Model.